# C: mysterious core dump at "printf"

Tags: c

I wrote a simple function that creates a "cd/dvd" which accepts 3 arguments: a name, a rating, and a "boolean" for whether that cd/dvd was ripped or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int makecd(char *Name, int Rating, int Ripped)
{
    if((Rating > 5) || (Rating < 0))
    {
        printf("Rating is wrong!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(Ripped = 0)
    {
        printf("Name: %s, Rating: %s/5, Ripped: false\n", Name, Rating);
        return(0);
    }
    else if(Ripped = 1)
    {
        printf("Name: %s, Rating: %s/5, Ripped: true\n", Name, Rating);
        return(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Value of \"Ripped\" not set correctly!\n");
        return(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    makecd("Avatar", 4, 1);
    /* std::cin.get(); */
    char Ignore[65536] = {'\0'};
    gets(Ignore);
    return 0;
}
```

After debugging some with dbx, I found out that the core dump is at line 18 (just after "if(Ripped = 1) { ... }"). What mystifies me is, why I am getting a core dump.

The output of dbx is as follows:

```
signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address) in strlen at 0xfee8645c
0xfee8645c: strlen+0x000c:      movl     (%eax),%edx
Current function is makecd
   18                   printf("Name: %s, Rating: %s/5, Ripped: false\n", Name, Rating);
```

Comment: `Ripped = 0` is an *assignment*. `gets` is *evil*. `Rating` is a *number*, which is not printed using `%s`. You need some good C book.

Comment: good way to catch yourself with this is when you are reading the code dont substitute the word "equals" for "=". Instead you should read it as "Ripped gets assigned the value 0". Def a beginner mistake, but eventually the difference between '=' and '==' will become second nature

Comment: `"Name: %s, Rating: %s`... --> `"Name: %s, Rating: %d`...

Comment: Rating is an integer but your format is %s. that's what's killing you. A good compiler would have reported that.

Comment: I don't see any code "making a CD/DVD". And **never ever** use `gets`! It has been removed from the standard 6 years ago and was deprectated since 1999. Every reasonable toolchain should warn about its usage, **do not ignore warnings**!

Comment: Thanks for the good responses. It seems I wasn't really looking well at my code (I was "speed-porting" a c++ application), so I made a few beginner mistakes. As for "`gets` is evil," what should I use for getting character arrays?

Comment: @Olaf Don't. Just don't. The definition of "make a CD/DVD" is subjective as it is, so don't worsen it.

Comment: @DistantGraphics: Both, CD and DVD are standardiseed things., i.e. small plastic discs. Every reasonable computer user would expect  you mean at least generation an ISO-file, if not also write (aka burn) this to the drive. My point is: Your question has nothing to do with CD or DVD, these ae just your semantics, unrelated to yur question/problem. Programming is about abstraction. It is a necessary, basic skill for being able to design&write programs.

Comment: @Olaf It's pointless to carry on with this conversation because A) Stack Overflow is not a forum, B) My question had nothing to do with what a CD/DVD is, and C) I can already see this turning into a discussion about "whether language is subjective or not."

Comment: use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead of `gets`. The reason for this is security,, `gets` will happily continue reading beyond your internal buffer size, making your code vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks. `fgets` allows you to limit the number of characters you read in.

Comment: why are fetching user input anyway? You're not going anything with it.

Comment: @yano The whole point of this was to compare memory usage between C and C++.  I needed the program to keep running so I could monitor memory usage using `prstat`. If you're interested in the results: I wrote the C++ program in about 3 minutes, and it ended up using 1.9 MiB of memory (RAM). The C program took me about 20 minutes and ended up using around 940 KiB of memory.

Comment: oh ok, good deal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier for `printf`:

```
printf("Name: %s, Rating: %s/5, Ripped: false\n", Name, Rating);
```

The `%s` specifier expects the address of a character array containing a null terminated string.  The first one is fine, but the second one is getting an `int` from the parameter list.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a crash.

If you want to print an integer, use the `%d` format specifier:

```
printf("Name: %s, Rating: %d/5, Ripped: false\n", Name, Rating);
```

Also, this is incorrect:

```
if(Ripped = 0)
```

This is not a comparison by an *assignment*.  To do a comparison, use the `==` operator:

```
if(Ripped == 0)
```

Comment: Oh dear! Quite embarrassing to say the least! Well, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @DistantGraphics Performing an assignment in a conditional statement isn't necessarily incorrect, it's perfectly valid to do that. Just make sure that is your intent (but pretty clear here your intent was comparison, not assignment). 0 is false, everything else is true. As such, `if(Ripped = 0)` will always be false and the compiler most likely optimized that entire code block out. Furthermore, `if(Ripped=1)` is always true, making its `else` always false. I bet if you look at the assembly all you'd see is code for the `else if (Ripped=1)` block.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int makecd(char *Name, int Rating, int Ripped){
if((Rating > 5) || (Rating < 0))
{
    printf("Rating is wrong!\n");
    return 1;
}

if(Ripped == 0)
{
    printf("Name: %s, Rating: %d/5, Ripped: false\n", Name, Rating);
    return(0);
}
else if(Ripped == 1)
{
    printf("Name: %s, Rating: %d/5, Ripped: true\n", Name, Rating);
    return(0);
}
else
{
    printf("Value of \"Ripped\" not set correctly!\n");
    return(1);
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
makecd("Avatar", 4, 1);
/* std::cin.get(); */
char Ignore[65536] = {'\0'};
gets(Ignore);
return 0;
}
```